Pool filter problem: dirt comes out the return jets
I have some experience with pools and here in Brazil we use filters of the company "Dancor" I don't know if they are common wherever you are. In one installation I noticed that dirt comes out the return jets when aspirating (vacuuming the fallout on) the floor. You might say that I'm supposed to use the "drain" setting not the "filter" mode when aspirating, but in this installation water is at a premium and so what I think is sensible is to aspirate in filter mode and then use the "retrowash" function (excuse my crude translation into whatever it may be called in English, never worked with pools in the US) to clean just the gunk off the filter with less waste of water. But again, the problem I noticed is that after that procedure, even though through the looking glass it seems the water is clear, when I switch back in filter mode a lot of gunk comes out the return jet. So this is frustrating. Is this a known issue with a defective filter assembly? Should I change the filter mode selector or the entire filter?

what is aspirating the floort

I take my filters out, and clean them with vacuum cleaner

@DYI75, a spelling mistake. Floor. Aspirating, vacuuming, the fallout.

There are no "filters" there is sand, it is one filter with sand in it.
